# What is string externalization?

Tags: string, internationalization

I'm learning best practices for internationalization and see that 'string externalization' comes up often. What does this mean? Looking up on google always results in people recommending some plugin for java, but I'm trying to come up with something on javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String externalization means, instead of writing:

```
console.log("Hello, world");
```

you load the string from an external source, like a text file or a database. The code then looks like this:

```
console.log(gettext("Hello, world"));
```

The `gettext` function then does the whole work of loading the externalized string. This is one of the ingredients for translating software.